# My getline and cout statement within my for loop are being truncated

Tags: c++, truncate, getline

For this code, it asks for the first song, and stores and prints it. But after the first entry, i'm asked if i would liek to continue like i wanted, but then after i type in Y, it skips over my song question and getline function and straight into asking about if i want to continue or not, what am i doing wrong here?

This is my output

Enter the name of the song. I need help
Do you want to continue (y/n)? y
Enter the name of a song. Do you want to continue (y/n)? y
Enter the name of a song. Do you want to continue (y/n)? y
Enter the name of a song. Do you want to continue (y/n)? n
There were 4 song titles entered.
I need help

Where as my wanted output and expected output is

Enter the name of the song. I need help
Do you want to continue (y/n)? y
Enter the name of a song. Printing
Do you want to continue (y/n)? y
Enter the name of a song. And entering
Do you want to continue (y/n)? y
Enter the name of a song. These songs
Do you want to continue (y/n)? n
There were 4 song titles entered.
I need help
Printing
And entering
These songs

```
/*This program will ask a user to enter a song list. By doing this each time that the     user enters
a song, he/she will then be asked if they want to enter another song, if yes then they     will enter another song.There will be a maximum of 15 songs.
This progarm will help a user keep track of their songs. But then the program will     output the amount of songs, and what they are.
input:A song. Then a yes or no, if yes, another song, if no the program will output.
output:The number of songs, and then the songs themselves, each song with it's own     individual line.
processing: There will be two functions, one of which will ask the user for the songs and     store them, and another for which will be computing
the output.
*/
    #include<iostream>
    #include<string>

using namespace std;

int input(string[15], int);
void printArray(string[15], int);

int main()
{
    const int arraysize=15;
    string songarray[arraysize];

     int x=input(songarray, arraysize);



      cout<<"There were "<<x<<" song titles entered.\n";
      printArray(songarray, x);
       return 0;
       }

/*This function will ask for the users input for a song and store the song in the     songarray. He or she
will then be asked whether or not they want to enter another song, if so, then they     will enter another song.
input:a song, y/Y or n/N for if they want to continue or not with another song
output:song will be sent to main function
processing: A while loop will be used for the user to enter is Y or N, and a for loop     (while loop nested) for the user to enter the 
songs
*/
int input(string titles[15], int rows)
{

      char answer='y';
      int k=0;
      for(int i=0;i<rows && (answer=='Y' || answer=='y');i++)
      {

           cout<<"Enter the name of a song. ";
           getline(cin, titles[i]);
           cout<<"Do you want to continue (y/n)? ";
           cin>>answer;
           k=i+1;
            }
           return k;
           }

/*The purpose of this function is to print the array from the main function.
input:accepts the array from the main function
output: prints the array
processing:nested loops will pring this array.
*/

void printArray(string playlist[15], int quantity)
{
    for(int j=0; j<quantity; j++)
    {
        cout<<playlist[j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this homework?  It's OK if it is, but we like to know.

Comment: try to use `cin >> titles[i]` instead of `getline`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your "cin>>answer" reads a single character but you type 'y' then press enter, so the the newline character is still sitting in cin. So when your loop goes back around getline just reads that newline character and you end up with an empty string.

If you do:

```
string dummy;
getline(cin, dummy);
```

after "cin>>answer" it will eat that trailing newline character.

Comment: it totally worked, it makes so much sense, because to me i was looking at the code and thinking, theres no way its just randomly skipping my cout statement it must be accepting another character or something. And now it makes sense, thank you1

Answer (score 2):

```
char answer;
cin >> answer;
```

indeed is the problem: look at [cin.ignore](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/ignore/) for another solution

Answer (score 0):

```
char answer;
cin >> answer;
```

Which keys did you press to answer the program's question? Which one ended up in `answer`? Which one remained in stdin, terminating the next getline before you get to type anything else?